# selecting checkbox value on select option and based on class attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select check box based on css class property if i have selected admin then it should select all check box with `.cb` and set value for selected checkbox to `true`.
If any one select then it should be select check box with property `.biller` and only selected check box value should be true similar for this

I tried code here https://jsfiddle.net/xrcwrn/79bm3Lfn/
this is not working properly how to make it proper.

Comment: Just change your `if` conditions and try. You have written `Admin`, it should be `admin` and instead of `Biller`, it should be `biller`

Comment: Please include the relevant – [mcve] – code in your question; don't just link to it.

Comment: If condition working when write in small letters in Admin and Biller( Milan also targeted on this) after that you can add id in test,test1and test2 than check condition if click 'test' then disable 'test1' and 'test2' and the checkbox in it and so on.

Comment: @MilanChheda I changed that.my problem first role selection is selecting proper check box but on changing to another it is not selecting another set of check box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the updated code:

```js
$(document).on('change', '#role', function() {
  $('input').prop('checked', false);
  var selectedValue = $(this).val();
  console.log(selectedValue);
  if (selectedValue === 'admin') {
    selectedValue = 'cb';
  }
  $("." + selectedValue).prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="role">
  <option value="admin">admin</option>
  <option value="biller">biller</option>
  <option value="hr">hr</option>
  <option value="sales">sales</option>
</select>
<div>
  <h3>Test <input type="checkbox" class="cb biller" /></h3>
  <span class="space">One <input type="checkbox" class="cb biller" id="pr" name="aa"/></span>
  <span class="space">
  Two
  <input type="checkbox" class="cb biller" id="pr" name="aa" />
  </span>
  <span class="space">Three <input type="checkbox" class="cb biller" id="pr" name="aa"/></span>
</div>
<div>
  <h3>Test1 <input type="checkbox" class="cb biller" /></h3>
  <span class="space">One <input type="checkbox" class="cb biller hr" id="pr" name="aa"/></span>
  <span class="space">
  Two
  <input type="checkbox" class="cb biller hr" id="pr" name="aa" />
  </span>
  <span class="space">Three <input type="checkbox" class="cb biller" id="pr" name="aa"/></span>
</div>
<div>
  <h3>Test2 <input type="checkbox" class="cb biller sales" /></h3>
  <span class="space">One <input type="checkbox" class="cb biller hr" id="pr" name="aa"/></span>
  <span class="space">
  Two
  <input type="checkbox" class="cb biller hr sales" id="pr" name="aa" />
  </span>
  <span class="space">Three <input type="checkbox" class="cb biller" id="pr" name="aa"/></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

check this code. you drop down value admin,biller etc so update   `if (selectedValue === "admin") , if (selectedValue === "biller")` etc

```js
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('change', '#role', function () {
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        if (selectedValue === "admin") {
            $(".cb").prop('checked', 'checked');
            $(".cb").val("true");
        }
        if (selectedValue === "biller") {
            $('.cb').prop("checked", false);
            $(".biller").prop('checked', 'checked');
            $(".biller").val("true");
        }
         if (selectedValue === "hr") {
            $('.cb').prop("checked", false);
            $(".hr").prop('checked', 'checked');
            $(".hr").val("true");
        }
        if (selectedValue === "sales") {
            $('.cb').prop("checked", false);
            $(".sales").prop('checked', 'checked');
            $(".sales").val("true");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="role">
  <option value="admin">admin</option>
  <option value="biller">biller</option>
  <option value="hr">hr</option>
  <option value="sales">sales</option>
</select>
<div>
  <h3>Test <input type="checkbox" class="cb biller" /></h3>
  <span class="space">One <input type="checkbox" class="cb biller" id="pr" name="aa"/></span>
  <span class="space">
  Two
  <input type="checkbox" class="cb biller" id="pr" name="aa" />
  </span>
  <span class="space">Three <input type="checkbox" class="cb biller" id="pr" name="aa"/></span>
</div>
<div>
  <h3>Test1 <input type="checkbox" class="cb biller" /></h3>
  <span class="space">One <input type="checkbox" class="cb biller hr" id="pr" name="aa"/></span>
  <span class="space">
  Two
  <input type="checkbox" class="cb biller hr" id="pr" name="aa" />
  </span>
  <span class="space">Three <input type="checkbox" class="cb biller" id="pr" name="aa"/></span>
</div>
<div>
  <h3>Test2 <input type="checkbox" class="cb biller sales" /></h3>
  <span class="space">One <input type="checkbox" class="cb biller hr" id="pr" name="aa"/></span>
  <span class="space">
  Two
  <input type="checkbox" class="cb biller hr sales" id="pr" name="aa" />
  </span>
  <span class="space">Three <input type="checkbox" class="cb biller" id="pr" name="aa"/></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain what have you changed other than what I mentioned above in the comment.

Comment: @MilanChheda i do not see your comment , i run this code and add jquery library and see alert value then give answer this

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam selecting first role is ok after changing role checkbox selection is not changing

Comment: @xrcwrn when you change role like hr ,sales then which checkbox you want to change?

Comment: for hr it should select check box with class hr.

Comment: please check now. hope all ok now